# Pipes Angular 2 dynamic Array Length

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-pipe

Is it posible to dynamically show length of array by using pipe? Here's my code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'lengthOfArray'
})
export class LengthOfArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): number {
    return value.length;
  }

}
```

I use it like this:

**Component**

```
listOfIdToExport: any[] = [];
```

**Template**

```
Element numer: {{ listOfIdToExport | lengthOfArray }}
```

I have a function which adds or removes elements from this array and problem is that pipe doesn't update array length when change occurs.

Comment: Why you don't you directly `Element numer: {{listOfIdToExport.length}}  - HTML`

Comment: Oo and did not know that it is so simple THX;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Value isn't updated when you add or remove item from an array because your pipe is pure. From Angular docs:

> Angular executes a pure pipe only when it detects a pure change to the
>   input value. A pure change is either a change to a primitive input
>   value (String, Number, Boolean, Symbol) or a changed object reference
>   (Date, Array, Function, Object).

So, you don't change object reference, you only update your array, therefore, solution is to make your pipe impure which will cause it to update value on every change detection cycle:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'lengthOfArray',
  pure: false
})

export class LengthOfArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any): number {
        return value.length;
    }

}
```

You can read more about pipes [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

Comment: Thanks it is working too i made it to much complicated

Answer (score 0):

A better solution will be to change the way you are adding and removing elements from `listOfIdToExport` array. You can change the reference to the array so that angular change detection works instead of making the pipe impure.